# How to Increase the size of TextArea in html razor view mvc4?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-validation

I have one text area field called **Description** in my view. I wish to increase the size of that field.

**My code**

```
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "required", style = " rows=10, columns=40" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
       </div>
     </div>
```

My TextArea

[image: TextArea]

I want to bring as like which is mention in the below image

[image: Wanted Output]

So i gave Rows and columns in textarea field. It increase the size of the text area. But when i shrink the page to phone size means all fields got shrink . But this textarea field is not shrink up to the page size. This is the issue

I kept validation for my fields. I want to show that validation in Red color. I'm using Model validation.

Answer (score 18):

Try This:

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, 10,40, htmlAttributes: new {style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" })
```

Answer (score 14):

While this is already answered, Someone out there might still need this.

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.comments, 
 new { @cols = "100", @rows =  "8", @style="width:100%;"})
```

Comment: That person is me. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`Rows` and `Cols` does not come under `style` tag. Its an independent attribute for `textarea`. You can write it as below.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "required", @cols = 40, @rows = 10})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove textArea element from site.css file. In site.css textarea max-width set as 280px;
Do like

input
,select
/*,textarea*/ 
{
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this MVC razor syntax will take only value
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.comment, 10, 40, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });

Answer (score -1):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, 10, 40, new { @class = "form-control required", style="max-width:75% !important;" })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 10, @rows = 10,@style="resize:both;" })
```

Comment: Explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,10,40, new { @class = "required"})

Comment: Please share some info around why your answer works instead of just pasting code.